# boost::filesystem adding quotation marks?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

When using boost_filesystem, Boost keeps adding quotation marks to the filenames.

foo.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    std::cout << argv[0] << std::endl;
    boost::filesystem::path p( argv[0] );
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
    std::cout << p.filename() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled:

```
g++ foo.cpp -o foo -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system
```

Output:

```
./foo
"./foo"
"foo"
```

This is somewhat unexpected, and inconvenient in my case. Is this really intentional, or is my somewhat older version of Boost (1.46.1) buggy in this respect? Is there some way I could avoid them being added?

I perused the documentation, but aside from the tutorials *not* showing those quotation marks in their example output, I was not enlightened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually a [bug](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5702) filed on the Boost framework on version 1.47.0.

The proposed workaround is:

```
std::cout << path("/foo/bar.txt").filename().string()
```

Answer (score 4):

It's intentional because unexpected embedded spaces and confuse related code. The best you can do is probably:

```
boost::replace_all(yourquotedstring, "\"", "");
```

**EDIT**

Although, according to [this link](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5702), you can try something like:

```
std::cout << path("/foo/bar.txt").filename().string();
```

Comment: Well, if I'm afraid of embedded spaces I can well add quotes myself. Having to *remove* them before I can use the filename in a log output is a nuisance though - and `replace_all()` doesn't really help because, brain-dead as it might be, there could be an embedded *quotation mark* in the filename as well. ;-)

Comment: Ok, but you could do what the bug report suggests: std::cout << p.filename().string() << std::endl;

Comment: Done, tested, and commited before I even upvoted / answered here. ;-)